# Problema de indexación con XPATH

Tags: javascript, web, scraping, xpath, console

Estoy aprendiendo XPATH para el Web Scraping, practicando un poco con la la lista de de videos de youtube, para que me devuelva los titulos de videos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el siguiente código me devuelve una lista con todos los elementos.

```js
$x("//ytd-compact-video-renderer//span[@id='video-title']/text()")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo entendido que si es que quiero que me devuelva el primer nombre, tendría que indexarlo con `[1]`, sin embargo me devuelve lo mismo

```js
$x("//ytd-compact-video-renderer//span[@id='video-title'][1]/text()")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obviamente la solución más correcta sería indexarlo con JavaScript, haciendo esto:

```js
$x("//ytd-compact-video-renderer//span[@id='video-title']/text()")[0]
```

Pero mi pregunta es **¿Por qué no funciona la anterior forma de indexar si es que la documentación de `XPATH` lo acepta?**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pienso que quieres `$x("(//ytd-compact-video-renderer//span[@id='video-title'])[1]/text()")` porque con XPath, si `expresión` selecciona una cantidad de elementos, la expresión `(expresión)[1]` selecciona el primer elemento.

En tu intento, sin `()` pero con `//span[@id='video-title'][1]`, el predicado posicional `[1]` se aplica para seleccionar cada primer elemento "hijo" `span[@id='video-title']` de su contenedor.

Comment: Uhhh.. gracias amigo